# Classe abstrata e propriedades em C#?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Ola, pessoal!

Seguinte, criei uma classe abstrata chamada Tabelas, onde classes de tabelas básicas do sistema herdarão dessa classe abstrata. Como Bairro, Cidade, Estados, categoria, etc..
O código da classe  abstrata está assim:

```
public abstract class Tabelas
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual int IdEstado { get; set; }
    public virtual int IdCidade { get; set; }
}
```

Acontece que, por exemplo, a classe Categoria que herda da abstrata, não contem os Campos IdEstado e IdCidade. Mas ao instanciá-la, o objeto faz referencia (acessa) essas duas propriedades. O mesmo acontece com a Classe Bairro, onde é para acessar apenas IdCidade, acessa também IdEstado.
Como implementar isso de forma mais performatica? Eu tenho que criar mais duas novas classes abstratas com IdEstado e IdCidade respectivamente, ou não definir esses dois atributos na classe abstrata, e sim definir somente na classe derivada?

Desculpe se fui confuso.

Obrigado.

Comment: É, está confuso. Talvez por isso que esteja com dificuldade para entender. Repense e tente escrever de uma forma menos confusa. Aí quem sabe vai até entender. Do jeito que está é difícil responder alguma coisa, teria que chutar o que você quer. Releia o texto escrito. Você já deve ter percebido que não faz muito sentido o que está escrito. Se você arrumar, fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: A classe abstracta só deve ter métodos e propriedades que devam existir **em todas** as derivadas. Ao criar a derivadas acrescente aqueles que lhe são relacionados.

Comment: Eu me pergunto até se você precisa realmente de uma classe abstrata. Quanto aos campos, herança faz isso, você precisa rever seus conceitos de modelagem para o projeto pelo exemplo, me parece que você tem vários objetos que precisam ser identificados por tipo e instância no sistema, algo como uma classe basica para todos (like Object). É isso?

Answer (score 4):

Você está vivenciando um problema bem comum que acontece quando vemos na herança uma solução para reutilização de código: **fica difícil achar na cadeia hierárquica a classe certa para publicar um atributo ou comportamento** e, por não encontrarmos a classe ideal, o membro acaba aparecendo onde deve e também onde não deve.

**Herança é aplicável para obter polimorfismo em uma relação hierárquica**. Se a relação não for hierárquica, usar interfaces pode ser mais adequado (e muitas vezes é mais adequado mesmo quando o relacionamento é naturalmente hierárquico).

Não é porque um atributo ou comportamento é útil em mais de um objeto que devemos usar herança para reaproveitá-lo ou "reutilizá-lo".

Para encontrar a modelagem ideal, investigue mais a fundo o problema. Qual problema você quer resolver com esta hierarquia? Quais são todas as entidades envolvidas?

**Considere ainda se você realmente precisa que os objetos na cadeia assumam a forma uns dos outros (polimorfismo)** ou se você está apenas tentando reutilizar código (ou pior: reutilizar apenas declarações de membros).

Pelas entidades listadas na pergunta, dá para concluir que o que você precisa é representar cada uma destas entidades na sua forma mais específica (*"Categoria"*, *"Estado"*, *"Cidade"* e *"Bairro"*), e precisa também representar todas elas na forma de *Tabela*.

Neste caso, esta modelagem atende e não sofre do problema de membros aparecendo onde não devem:

```
interface Tabela
    int Id
    string Nome

class Categoria : Tabela
    int Id // implementação exigida pela interface Tabela
    string Nome // implementação exigida pela interface Tabela

class Estado : Tabela
    int Id // implementação exigida pela interface Tabela
    string Nome // implementação exigida pela interface Tabela

class Cidade: Tabela
    int IdEstado

    int Id // implementação exigida pela interface Tabela
    string Nome // implementação exigida pela interface Tabela

class Bairro : Tabela
    int IdCidade

    int Id // implementação exigida pela interface Tabela
    string Nome // implementação exigida pela interface Tabela
```